# How to align the menu in Combo box towards left side in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, text-alignment

How to align the menu in Combo box towards left side in Ext JS

[image: Current Style]

[image: I need to be display like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ext js +4 versions have pickerAlign property

```
xtype: 'combobox',
pickerAlign: 'tr-br',
...
```